# In a brand new electron-react-typescript app when executing 'yarn start': "All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron

I'm a brand new comer to React.js and, following these indications: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/ I first created an empty react.js -typescript app

nano tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Then, with these indications: https://medium.com/bobble-engineering/create-a-desktop-app-using-electron-and-react-b23b435c0506 I installed electron.js, and created in /src electron.ts :

src/electon.ts :

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000')

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

This is package.json :

```
{
  "name": "react-ggc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "src/electron.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.14",
    "@types/node": "^14.10.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.49",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "electron ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^10.1.2"
  }
}
```

When I execute first the electron app :
yarn electron .
everything looks fine:

[image]

But when I execute the webapp part with yarn start, for few seconds the standard empty webapp appears, but it is promptly replaced by this error: "All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.  TS1208"

[image]

If in tsconfig.js I comment the line about isolvatedModules :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    //"isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
 ]
}
```

when executing again 'yarn start' command to start the webapp, I get the same error:

```
Failed to compile.

/home/marco/webMatters/electronMatters/react-ggc/src/electron.ts
TypeScript error in /home/marco/webMatters/electronMatters/react-ggc/src/electron.ts(1,1):
All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.  TS1208

  > 1 | const electron = require('electron')
     | ^
    2 | const app = electron.app
    3 | const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
    4 |
```

And to my surprise tsconfig.json file has been rewritten again:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

It seems that executing the command 'yarn start' overwrites the file tsconfig.json.

How to solve the problem?
Looking forward to your kind help